# Removing jquery click event handler from child elements of a table row

Tags: jquery, html, click

I have a table with a checkbox on the first column. When I click anywhere on the row, a class 'row_selected' is set on the table row and the checkbox is checked. The code is as follows:

```
$('#my_table > tbody > tr > td').live('click', function() {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('row_selected')) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('row_selected')
        $('td.checkbox input', this.parentNode).prop("checked", false)
    } else {
        $(this).parent().addClass('row_selected')
        $('td.checkbox input', this.parentNode).prop("checked", true)
    }
})
```

The problem is some of the table cells have buttons which if clicked, I do not want the row to become selected. i.e.

```
<tr>
    <td class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="false"/>
    </td>
    <td>blah<td>
    <td>
        <a class="myButton">do stuff</a>
    </td>
    <td>blah<td>
</tr>
```

I want the jquery click event to work except when I click on myButton.

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couldn't you just stop propagation on the myButton class elements?

```
$('a.myButton').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});​
```

Here's a simplified **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2feV7/)** using your code that shows how the td click triggers work except when clicking the link.

Comment: you shouldn't use stopPropagation because he is using .live as it says here: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: @GuilhermeDaviddaCosta - sure it does. Click the first blah a few times and watch the checkbox toggle.

Comment: @GuilhermeDaviddaCosta - oh and in response to your concern about stopPropagation() and live(), the OP can simply adjust his code to use the newer .on().

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#my_table > tbody > tr > td').live('click', function() {
    if ($(this).children('a.myButton').length) return true; // prevents click on link
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('row_selected')) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('row_selected')
        $('td.checkbox input', this.parentNode).prop("checked", false)
    } else {
        $(this).parent().addClass('row_selected')
        $('td.checkbox input', this.parentNode).prop("checked", true)
    }
})
```

Where you try to find a link inside your td and if it finds it will return true so the link will continue working. (return false if you don't want the link to be performing the "click" action)

Created a simple example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ezh8t/).

Although you could use `.stopPropagation` if you change `.live` to `.on`

```
$('a.myButton').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});​

$('#my_table > tbody > tr > td').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('row_selected')) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('row_selected')
        $('td.checkbox input', this.parentNode).prop("checked", false)
    } else {
        $(this).parent().addClass('row_selected')
        $('td.checkbox input', this.parentNode).prop("checked", true)
    }
})
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xPBve/) you can see a different example where `.stopPropagation` works without using `.live`.
It will work only with jQuery1.7+

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers." - [http://api.jquery.com/live/](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Thanks for the update, OP used live and I copied his code just to change little things.

Comment: Added another solution using `.on`

Answer (score 1):

I do it by getting the event source at the start of the method and returning if it's not what I was expecting.  For example

```
function getEventSrc(e)
{
    var eventIsFiredFromElement = e.target;
    if(eventIsFiredFromElement==null)
    {
        // I.E.
        eventIsFiredFromElement = e.srcElement;
    }
    return(eventIsFiredFromElement.type);
}
```

Returns what type of element was clicked.  Looks like you want to stop if it's a button.

```
$('#my_table > tbody > tr > td').live('click', function(ev) {
    // Make sure event is not comming from a button.
    if(getEventSrc(ev) == 'button'){return;}

    if ($(this).children('a.myButton').length) return true; // prevents click on link
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('row_selected')) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('row_selected')
        $('td.checkbox input', this.parentNode).prop("checked", false)
    } else {
        $(this).parent().addClass('row_selected')
        $('td.checkbox input', this.parentNode).prop("checked", true)
    }
})
```